# Apache's multisite main IP accesible via web

Tags: apache-2.4

Good day. I'm sorry in advance if this question sounds noob enough.

I have an Apache serving like 6 websites working fine. However if I browse my server's IP, one of those sites gets shown in the browser... even when in its .conf file there's nothing about that IP.

This put me the question in action. What's the best practice to deal with the fact that the IP wont be accesible via web?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is that Apache httpd will serve the vhost defined in the host: header or if none are matched then the default vhost will be served. If there is no explicit default vhost then the first defined vhost is considered the default.
You can configure a vhost first that serves a blank page or maybe an IP based vhost. Some examples from the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Using a catch all will also catch anyone addressing your server via a different DNS name, from a name in their hosts files, etc.  Good practice.

Comment: This ^^^ and return 444